# What are counter examples for these statements?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

> Question 1.
>
> Let $\{T_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family topologies on a set $X$.
>
> Provide an example that $\bigcup T_i$ is not a topology on X.

>

> Question 2.
>
> Let $X$ be a compact space and $Y$ be a topological space.
>
> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous bijection.
>
> Provide an example that $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

What are these two counter examples?

For Question 1, I think two non-comparable(for the order $\subset$) topologies should be given, but I cannot think of one since every finite dimensional normed space has the unique topology under any norm. I cannot think of an example that is not a finite-dimensional topological space.

For Question 2, $Y$ must not be Hausdorff. Likewise above, I cannot think of an explicit example which is not Hausdorff...

Comment: Oh, by the way, this is the 294,000th question on this site.

Comment: There is a three element solution to question 1.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't get what you mean/... Would you please be specific?

Comment: There is a set with three elements having two topologies each containing three elements whose union is not a topology.

Comment: For question 2, $X$ and $Y$ are equivalent as sets, so you might as well look for examples $f:X \rightarrow X$.  Then the only possible difference is two different topologies on the same set.

Comment: @Eric Towers: There is even a zero element solution to question 1!

Comment: @Servaes:  True.  $I = \varnothing$ is such.  Doesn't work for $X = \varnothing$ though since all topologies on $\varnothing$ have one element.  Not nearly so symmetric as my quip above...  :-)

Comment: @Eric Towers: It does work for $X=\varnothing$, because $\bigcup_{i\in I}T_i=\varnothing$ if $I=\varnothing$, which isn't a topology on any space, including $X=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Servaes:  Intended to use "the null set trick" only once per example, so intended $X = \varnothing, I \neq \varnothing$.  No biggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question one take $I=\varnothing$.

For question two take $X=Y=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete resp. trivial topologies, i.e.
$$T_X=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad T_Y=\{\varnothing,\{0,1\}\}.$$
Then taking for $f:\ X\ \longrightarrow\ Y$ the identity will do.

Answer (score 2):

A non-trivial example for question one: let $X = \{1,2,3\}$.

Take $T_1 = \{\emptyset,\{1\},X\}$, and $T_2 = \{\emptyset,\{2\},X\}$.  Note that $T_1 \cup T_2$ is not a topology.